# políticas de laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero validar que otros usuarios no puedan editar un producto si no les pertenece estoy usando políticas de laravel pero tengo que verificar que empresa esta usando ese usuario y luego si validar si a esa empresa pertenece el producto este es mi código

```
public function update(User $user, Productos $productos)
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $id_empresa = Empresa::where('fk_id_user', $id)->get();
       $empresa = $id_empresa['id_empre'];
        return $empresa == $productos;
    }
```

pero siempre marca que no tengo autorización.

Comment: No veo dónde está definida la variable $producto.

Comment: el no debería recibir la variable del el método del controlador

Comment: `$productos= Productos::find($request->id_p);
         $this->authorize('update',$productos);
                         ]);`

Comment: Estoy hablando de $producto, en singular, no de $productos

Comment: fue un error aunque ya lo corregí y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: en la documentación de las policies lo realizan de esta forma: `public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }`

Comment: pero el post esta ligado directamente al id del usuario no hallo la lógica para unir el usuario la empresa y el producto ya que esta de por medio la empresa

Comment: Lo primero es que en el return estas comparando 2 objetos diferentes por lo que siempre va a retornar false. Lo segundo es que nos explique que relación existe entre las tablas y aclares los criterios para aplicar la política para que de esta forma podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser varias cosas,

1- El primer problema es en empresa el `get()` te devuelve una colección de modelos. Para obtener el modelo usa `first()`.

2- *$productos* , imagino, que es una colección de modelos, lo mismo hay que seleccionar el producto `first()` y comparar solo el id de empresa, yo le he llamado *id_empre*, pero no se si producto tiene ese atributo

```
public function update(User $user, Productos $productos)
    {
        $empresa = Empresa::where('fk_id_user', \Auth::id())->first(); 
        return $empresa->id_empre == $productos->first()->id_empre;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que fijarse que dependiendo de la relación si es una `hasMany-belongsTo (1:N)(N:1)` o `belongsToMany (N:M)`.

### Where Has , no usar el id a pelo

Eloquent con `whereHas`, si están bien formadas las relaciones en un caso accederá a la tabla del usuario , o a la tabla pivote , de forma automññatica gracias a eloquent , por eso es más recomendable usar `whereHas` que hacerlo con id's a pelo , porque si cambias la relación por requisitos del cliente , tienes que rehacer las consultas , mientras que con `whereHas` no tienes porqué , solamente la forma de asociarlo tanto con `$usuarios->empresa()->attach($empresa)` o `$usuario->empresa()->associate($empresa);`.

```
public function update(User $user, Productos $productos)
{
    $empresa = Empresa::whereHas('usuario',function($qUsuario){
       $qUsuario->where('id_user',Auth::id());
    })->first();

    $productoEmpresa = $productos::whereHas('empresa',function($qEmpresa) use ($empresa){
       $qEmpresa->where('id_empre',$empresa->id_empre);
    })->first();
    if($empresa == null || $productoEmpresa == null){
      return false;
    }else{
      return $empresa->id_empre == $producto->id_empre;
    }
}
```

Podra haber problemas de foraneas y demás , que no se el nombre de dichos ids , pero espero que cogas el concepto.

### First y get

Con `first`, llamas al primer elemento existente , si es una relación de varios , cogerás el primero de los N-elementos que encuentres en la busqueda.
Con `get`, como dice mi compañero coges todos los elementos y te lo devuelve en un array de colecciones.